Why is my slot not rerendered when toggling v-if
I have 3 components like the following:
IsLoadingComponent.vue
<template>
   <div class="loading-spinner" v-if="isLoading"></div>
   <slot v-else></slot>
</template>

<script setup>
defineProps<{isLoading: boolean}>()
</script>

Template.vue
<template>
   <Header/>
   <IsLoading>
      <slot></slot>
   </IsLoading>
</template>

<script setup>
defineProps<{isLoading: boolean}>()
</script>

Component.vue
<template>
   <Template :isLoading="isLoading">
      <form>...</form>
   </Template>
</template>

<script setup>
const isLoading = ref(false)
async fetch() {
  isLoading.value = true
  try {
    isLoading.value = false
    ...some async operation
  } finally {
    isLoading.value = true
  } 
}
</script>

Initially, the page renders correctly (from SSR). However, when after triggering fetch, vue doesn't render the <form> element anymore.
Inspecting the DOM, i can see that it is rendered as <template> #document fragment <form></form> </template> instead of just <form></form>
Does anybody know why this is the case?

In the template component you do not pass the prop down the the loading component.

Also check that the rest of the state is properly set as you expect it to be.

Finally, it is supposed to be kebab case for the props aka :is-loading="isLoading".

"Template " name is ambiguous. And fwiw, you're reproducing something that is already done by Suspense

Ok, so the question doesn't entire reflect the issue.
My component was actually like this
Component.vue
<template>
   <MyTemplate :isLoading="isLoading">
      <template>
         <form>...</form>
      </template>
   </MyTemplate>
</template>

which somehow cause vue to render the slot as a literal template.
However, if I either remove template or add v-slot:default, then it correctly renders. So it should be like this
Component.vue
<template>
   <MyTemplate :isLoading="isLoading">
      <form>...</form>
   </MyTemplate>
</template>

or
Component.vue
<template>
   <MyTemplate :isLoading="isLoading">
      <template v-slot:default>
         <form>...</form>
      </template>
   </MyTemplate>
</template>

Personally, I think this might be a bug in Vue
